# Implementing Quick Look QLPreviewController Animations

Tags: iphone, ios5, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to implement the following method of QLPreviewControllerDelegate and the method requires me to return the view that shows my Preview Item before the Preview Controller; this should be self.view however I am getting the following compile error:

```
Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'UIView *__autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC
```

How to I fix this?

```
//Called when a Quick Look preview is about to be presented full screen or dismissed, to     provide a zoom effect.

- (CGRect)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller frameForPreviewItem:(id <QLPreviewItem>)item inSourceView:(UIView **)view
{

    // Set the source view  
    view = self.view;

    // Set the Rectangle of the Icon
    return self.view.bounds; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view parameter is a pointer to a pointer to a view.  To set it, you'd use this syntax:

```
*view = self.view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post an answer here updating this, since there aren't many other questions surrounding it.

The above function doesn't appear to be called anymore in iOS16. Per WWDC2019, the new recommendation for animating/zooming from a thumbnail is with this method:

```
func previewController(
    _ controller: QLPreviewController,
    transitionViewFor item: QLPreviewItem
) -> UIView? {
    //sample code getting a thumbnail code from a collectionview
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: selectedImageIndex, section: 0)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! ImageListCell
    return cell.imageView
}
```

As the OP mentioned, be sure to add the extension:

```
QLPreviewControllerDelegate
```

and set the delegate when launching the preview:

```
let previewController = QLPreviewController()
previewController.dataSource = self
previewController.delegate = self //<--- set this or else animations wont happen
present(previewController, animated: true)
```